# How to make $ionicLoading.show() last for atleast given time

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing an ionic app where I load content dynamically on click event. I am using `$ionicLoading.show()` before hitting the API and `$ionicLoading.hide()` after getting the response.

I wish to retain `loading`  atleast for 3 seconds even if data is completely loaded for some undefined reasons without using **`$timeout`**. I tried `duration` in `$ionicLoading.show()` but that does'nt help. Is this possible, if so how can I achieve that.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {
                                $ionicLoading.hide();
                            }, 3000)`

Comment: It same as using `$timeout`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  This will put a duration for the loading animation to show. After 3000 milliseconds the loader will auto hide

```
$ionicLoading.show({duration:3000});
```

Comment: Please **describe** your answer and not just using **code**. Otherwise may your answer will be deleted!